# Unable to install pyzmail - "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x

I am trying to install pyzmail for Python 3.4. I am using Visual Studio Community Edition (Windows) but have also tried to install using the command line and get the following dump:

```
 ----- Installing 'pyzmail' -----
Collecting pyzmail
  Using cached pyzmail-1.0.3.tar.gz
Collecting distribute (from pyzmail)
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\distribute.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\distribute.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\distribute.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\distribute.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info\distribute.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2680, in _dep_map
        return self.__dep_map
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2525, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 177, in run
        writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
        if require: self.require(env, installer)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
        from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
    ImportError: No module named '_markerlib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5zvr2p3\distribute\
----- Failed to install 'pyzmail' -----
```

After Googling, I checked I had the ez_setup and setuptools modules installed, which I do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce your problem, and you're right, using `pip install pyzmail` wont' be good (pyzmail's installer is buggy) so i've tried this instead:

```
easy_install pyzmail
```

And it succeed, then I could just import pyzmail without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try installing the pyzmail36 fork, which installs the same modules for Python 3.6 and later: `pip install pyzmail36` on Windows and `pip3 install pyzmail36` on Linux and macOS.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I wrote this question while reading your book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python", which was fantastic - thank you for getting me started in programming!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `easy_install pyzmail`

That worked for me in 2020.